# TSQL Default column value in temporary table

Tags: function, t-sql, default, temporary

When I try to create this table, there is an error saying that `fns_GetSomeDate` is not recognized:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    id INT,
    validity datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (dbo.fns_GetSomeDate())
)
```

and the error: "Column "`dbo`" is not allowed in this context, and the user-defined function or aggregate "`dbo.fns_GetSomeDate`" could not be found." is returned.

But when I try to create the same table but not as a temp table (without the "#") everything works OK:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTable (
    id INT,
    validity datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (dbo.fns_GetSomeDate())
)
```

Function does exist. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: When you create a temporary table, it's stored in `tempdb`. I guess it's because your function doesn't exist in that database?

Comment: That's interesting. The function is missing in the `tempdb`. You need to create it first there. But when the `tempdb` objects are clear due to restart or something else, you are going to use the function. Also, I have try to use `database.schema.function_name` in the `default` constraint, but it is not allowed.

Comment: That is what i suspected at the start, that the problem is scope related. I have tried `some_db.dbo.fns_GetSomeDate` and it didn't work either, Error: The name "some_db" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted. I've tried to store the value form the fuction in a local variable, but ''Variables are not allowed in the CREATE TABLE statement."

Comment: @user3246112 Yes, exactly. Could share the function body? It might be possible to use the code directly in the create statement?

Comment: The function body is simple, just returns a date based upon a literal. Replacing call to function with this literal is a re-refactoring as this was the initial state. This literal was used in many places and I wanted to avoid any magic literals and replace it with a nice function.

Comment: @user3246112 simplify your code. Why do you need a default in a *temp* table? Why do you need a temp table to begin with? Why not modify the *INSERT* statement that fills the table?

Comment: @user3246112 `date based on a literal` why not use PARSE then? Or a valid *date literal* like `20170929` or `2917-09-20T17:24:54` ?

Comment: This is a part of an enterprise solution and one of many places it occurred. Getting rid of temp tables altogether is too time consuming at the moment. It would cause system wide refactoring.
@PanagiotisKanavos how using `PARSE` will allow me to get rid of the same literal with date in many places in TSQL codebase?

Comment: @user3246112 you haven't provided the function code. What literal are you talking about? Where does it come from? Why is it a string instead of a date-typed value in the database? If it is a string, why not a *date* literal so no function or parsing is required?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the function in `tempdb`, then it will work.

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_getdate()
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dt datetime
    SELECT @dt = GETDATE()
    RETURN @dt
END

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    id INT,
    validity AS dbo.fn_getdate()
)
```

Comment: Yes, creating function in temp database will work, however this is an enterprise solution and it is a dirty hack :)

Comment: @user3246112 you mean, having a temp table with a default value that comes from a function? Most likely. If you use such a hack though, you have to provide the *correct* function name. Temporary tables are created in tempdb. `dbo.Whatever` refers to the current database. If you use it in a tempdb object, it refers to tempdb. If you want to use a function that is defined in a *different* database, you'd have to provide the db name as well, eg `myDb.dbo.MyFunc`. Probably won't work though - default values have many restrictions